# What is the minimum needed to make a BindingList<myClass> available in VS 2008 Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am setting the datasource of a control at runtime to BindingList which works fine.

But I would prefer if I could see this in the designer which would mean that I could select the datamember properties at design time, rather than having to set them at runtime also.

What is the minimum requirements to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you will have to do the following:

- Add New Data Source ( and you can select your class object)
- when you bind to grid or any user control, it will create BindingSource (or you can use existing one).
- You can then bind your BindingList

As long as your class has public {get; } properties stuff it will be visible in Data Source and in your Grid (as columns for example)

[See MDSN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ckyxa83%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from anvarbek raupov is simplier, what I ended up doing was talking an existing working class which implemented a few unnessary interfaces and ripping bits out until I got down to something like the following.

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class myClassList : BindingList<myClass> , IComponent 
{
    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    public ISite Site { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```